# Java stax: Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, stax

I am trying to parse a xml using stax but the error I get is:

```
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[8,64]
Message: Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.
```

I have already tried to look it up but couldn't find a solution. The code I have to parse it is:

```
public List<Vild> getVildData(File file){
    XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
    try {
        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
        XMLStreamReader reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(byteArrayInputStream);
        List<Vild> vild = saveVild(reader);
        reader.close();
        return vild;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
private List<Vild> saveVild(XMLStreamReader streamReader) {
    List<Vild> vildList = new ArrayList<>();
    try{
        Vild vild = new Vild();
        while (streamReader.hasNext()) {
            streamReader.next();
            //Creating list with data
        }
    }catch(XMLStreamException | IllegalStateException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

I have already tried the following that I found online:

```
XMLStreamReader reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(byteArrayInputStream,"UTF-8");
```

But that didn't work. Does someone know a solution for this problem?

Comment: I think there may be a problem between the actual encoding of your file, and the encoding declared at the beginning of your XML. Do you have a way to show what's in this file? Especially the `<?xml ?>` declaration at the very beginning, and what's around line 8?

Comment: At line 8 it was tuck on ë but when I change it to latin-1 or ansi that one goes away but get this one instead: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[414,47]
Message: The reference to entity "R" must end with the ';' delimiter. On that line it get stuck on P&R

Comment: Where have you changed the encoding? In the XML declaration, or when saving the XML file (physically). Alse, the & **must** be escaped with &amp; in an XML, but it is separate issue, not related to encoding.

Comment: I solved it in the end by changing it to this line: factory.createXMLStreamReader(byteArrayInputStream, "iso8859-1");. So inside the java code itself

Comment: "P&R" is not valid XML. Can you change how this "almost XML" file is generated so that it actually follows all the rules required? - I see you've opened a new question for this new issue, that's good

Comment: @Joni no I can't change this. Other people should be able to upload files like this to the program. I can't change the output the other program creates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML file is not encoded in UTF-8. Try to find out what the encoding is.

If the encoding turns out to be "latín 1" for example, use that when you create the xml reader:

```
XMLStreamReader reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(byteArrayInputStream,"ISO8859-1")
```